# Setting a custom UITableView tableHeaderView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I'm working on a project and I'm trying to set the table view header to a complex View. This project does not use auto layout and all constrains are handled programatically. I have a Parent View controller that contains the table view.

Here is the code for the parent view controller (Delegate and Data Source are in parent)

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.array = [NSMutableArray new];

  [self.array addObject:@"One"];
  [self.array addObject:@"Two"];
  [self.array addObject:@"Three"];
  [self.array addObject:@"Four"];

  [self.view addSubview:self.detailedTableView];
}

- (void)updateViewConstraints
{

  [super updateViewConstraints];

  NSDictionary *views = @{
                          @"detailedTable": self.detailedTableView,
                          };



  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[detailedTable]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[detailedTable]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

                                                   constant:0.f]];


}

-(UITableView *)detailedTableView
{
  if(!_detailedTableView)
  {
    _detailedTableView = [UITableView new];
    _detailedTableView.dataSource = self;
    _detailedTableView.delegate   = self;
    _detailedTableView.separatorStyle                 = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    _detailedTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator   = NO;
    _detailedTableView.separatorInset                 = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    _detailedTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  }

  return _detailedTableView;
}
```

In the child view controller that inherits from the parent, I'm trying to set the header view to a custom view that is contained in the child view controller. Here is the relevant code:

```
@interface ChildViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView        *testView;
@end

@implementation ChildViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.detailedTableView.tableHeaderView = self.testView;
}

-(UIView *)testView
{
  if(!_testView)
  {
    _testView = [UIView new];
    _testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    _testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
  }

  return _testView;
}

- (void)updateViewConstraints
{

  [super updateViewConstraints];

  NSDictionary *views = @{
      @"test"         : self.testView
  };

  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[test(width)]-0-|" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[test(100)]" options:0 metrics:metrics views:views]];


}
```

I'm not setting the widths or heights through the frame property but rather through the constraints. However, this code produces the image below on iOS 8.1 and completely crashes on iOS 7.1

I can see that the dummy view is being added but it is not in the appropriate place to be the tableHeaderView as it is covering up the other array items in the UITable. Plus this doesn't work on iOS 7.1 as it throws this error message:

```
  *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794
    2015-01-03 22:33:05.540 Saloote A[10073:607] This is where we save the application data during a exception
    2015-01-03 22:33:05.541 Saloote A[10073:607] Exception: Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UITableView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.
```

[image]

Comment: Overriding the method, you should call super first. So, move `[super updateViewConstraints]` to upper in `updateViewConstraints` method.

Comment: I would take a guess and say that `updateViewConstraints` isn't being called when you think it is; specifically, your view's constraints for the header are being called after the tableview is set up. So since the `tableHeaderView` is normally nil, the table isn't updated to reflect the addition of it. Throw some breakpoints in your code in the methods you're listing and make sure the application's flow is matching your intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because your test's view is not subview of vc.view directly.

You can only add constraints for your child view.

You can use setFrame instead of autoLayout.

Comment: What should the flow be then, should it be something like:         [self.view addSubview:self.testView];

  self.detailedTableView.tableHeaderView = self.testView; Because I tried this approach but still run into the same problem.

Comment: I can get the view height for the custom view and use that for the height property in the CGRect frame for the headerView. Thank you for this answer, this worked.